# How to get column name for a unique_constraint violation?

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I am using the pq driver and I'm wondering why the pq.Error gives an empty Column when I face a unique constraint violation.

I could parse `Detail` but is there any reason why `Column` would be empty?  It would be preferable if I could just get `email` from `Column` instead of parsing `Detail`

Here is what the error looks like:

```
Severity:"ERROR"
Code:"23505"
Message:"duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_users""
Detail:"Key (email)=(user3@email.com) already exists."
Hint:""
Position:""
InternalPosition:""
InternalQuery:""
Where:""
Schema:"public"
Table:"users"
Column:""
DataTypeName:""
Constraint:"unique_users"
File:"nbtinsert.c"
Line:"534"
Routine:"_bt_check_unique"
```

Unfortunately, the `Column` value is empty.  I'm trying to come up with error messaging for my application and I'm wondering if there is some way to get that information so I can enhance the message why the entity was not created and let the caller know the field (`email` in this case) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The specific error message (including the violated constraint and column/value) is in the field `Detail`.

**EDIT**:

I guess `Column` is empty, because the unique constraint might affect multiple columns. `Constraint` offers the constraint name, in combination with `Schema` and `Table` you can look up this constraint in `pg_constraint`. Field `conkey` might hold the references to the covered attributes.

Comment: Right.  I am wondering why the `Column` is an empty string.  If I could just get the `Column` without having to parse the `Detail` to grab the field name, then that would be preferable.  Am I doing something wrong that the `Column` is empty?

Comment: I guess ```Column``` is empty, because the unique constraint might affect multiple columns. ```Constraint``` offers the constraint name, in combination with ```Schema``` and ```Table``` you can loo up this constraint in ```pg_constraint```. Field ```conkey``` might hold the references to the covered attributes.

Comment: You mean that `conkey` *will* hold the references to the columns.